# How to Remove/Disable Provisioning Profile Expiration Warning

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, provisioning

I have a few provisioning profiles on my iPhone/iPad device.

Every day it annoys me with the following messagebox:

"Provisioning Profile Expiration: The provisioning profile X will expire in Y days"
With two buttons: "Show Me" and "Remind Me"... regardless what I pick it'll pop up within another day or so.

Is there a way to disable these warnings? I don't want to see them at all!

Thanks

Comment: If one of the answer satisfied your question, please accept one of them.  Otherwise consider updating your question or adding a comment.  Also, it's ok to post your own answer and mark your answer as accepted if none of the other solutions worked for you.

Answer (score 10):

iPCU no longer works for me and from what I can tell is deprecated. For XCode 6.1 I was able to delete specific provision profiles from devices under **Window** > **Devices**:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

On your iphone Go to Settings, then General, then scroll down until you see the name of the offending provision, the click it and chose delete. :)

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 4):

I have run into this problem as well.  The best way to remove them, without XCode installed, is to use the [iphone configuration utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl851).  You can download this for [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl851) or [PC](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl926).  Your device must be plugged in in order to do this.

Here is a picture of using the iphone configuration utility to delete provisioning profiles:

[image]

Note that this is not the only way.

If you have XCode installed, I would recommend using organizer to delete the provisioning profiles.  In Organizer, select the "Devices" list.  Then choose your device (must be plugged in).  Then choose "Provisioning Profiles" under your device.  From here you can make multiple selections (hold shift key) and then hit delete key to remove them.

Comment: It could be removed without `iphone configuration utility`.. Settings->General->Profiles

Comment: @Nekto I know, but I've found that using the iphone configuration utility is faster.  Note that my answer indicates there are multiple ways to remove provisioning profiles: `(not the only way)`.  I think they can be removed in organizer as well.  Actually, organizer might be the best way since it looks like it allows multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove that profiles.
2. Ask the developer of that apps to renew that profiles, ask to send them to you and update them on your  device

If you choose first variant then you won't be able to launch apps that are bound to that profiles.

Answer (score -1):

Either delete them if you aren't using them, or renew them. I don't think there is a way to supress this message.

Answer (score -1):

Revoke, then create a new Provisioning Profile from the iOS Dev Center.  This should extend the expiration date to a year or so from the day you make a new profile.

Check to make sure you dont have duplicate certs/private keys in all keychains.